# How do I animate title of site in browser tab?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, page-title

How do I animate site title of site in browser tab like this?

Screen capture GIF:
[image: image description]

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731357/how-do-i-make-text-inside-the-title-tag-animate-using-javascript).

Comment: Please do not animate page titles.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a scroll animation to the title of your browser tab using this Javascript code:

```
msg = "Title";
msg = " ...Just a scrolling title example" + msg;position = 0;
function scrolltitle() {
document.title = msg.substring(position, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, position); position++;
if (position > msg.length) position = 0
window.setTimeout("scrolltitle()",170);
}
scrolltitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `window.setTimeout()` or `window.setInterval()` and change `document.title`

Comment: It is not the window.location, it is the title

Comment: Oops.  You're 100% right.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure js...

```js
function recursiveAnimateTitle(string) {
  let firstLetter = string[0];
  let title = document.querySelector('title');
  title.innerHTML += firstLetter;
  if (string.length > 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      recursiveAnimateTitle(string.substring(1));
    }, 100);
  }
}

function animateTitle(string) {
  document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = "";
  recursiveAnimateTitle(string);
}

animateTitle('Example Title');
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Some Default Title</title>
</head>
<body></body>
```

If you want to vary the time for each letter, use math.random with a range.

With a distribution if you want to get really weird with it.