# Highlight blink browser tab/window

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Using JavaScript, can we blink/highlight browser tab/window and if possible the taskbar icon too. This is to bring attention of the user to the tab/window.

Comment: No, (thankfully) but consider the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) as an alternative.

Comment: You can consider changing favicon of the website or title of it.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible. JavaScript does not have access to that kind of functionality.

**EDIT:** [Animating the text of the tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731357/how-do-i-make-text-inside-the-title-tag-animate-using-javascript) is the closest thing you are going to get to this kind of functionality.

Comment: If you had seen the google chat's(Gsuite) browser tab highlighting, you wouldn't say that!..

Comment: @Kuppusamy do you have any code to support your comment?

Comment: Check this out https://gist.github.com/mbohanon/def685be086a44b833d37fe0cccf17c9