# Date time running line in <title> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript program that displays the current date and time in a page title (), then I tried to animate this header as a crawl line, but nothing works. Tried using the slice method, as well as the substring method, but nothing came out of it.

```js
function updateDateTime() {
  let datetime = new Date();
  let datetimeString = datetime.toLocaleString();
  document.title = datetimeString;
}
setInterval(updateDateTime, 1000); // оновлюємо час кожну секунду

updateDateTime();

let marquee = document.getElementById("marquee");
let datetime = document.getElementById("datetime");

function shiftDateTime() {
  const unit = "px";
  let position = Number.parseInt(datetime.style.right) || 0;
  let width = datetime.offsetWidth;

  position = position > marquee.offsetWidth ?
    -width :
    position + 1;

  datetime.style.right = position + unit;
  requestAnimationFrame(shiftDateTime);
}

shiftDateTime();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Date&Time marquee</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="marquee">
    <span id="datetime"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my code, all I was able to do was display the current date and time in the title. In the end, our program should display the current date and time in the page title and animate them as a running line right-to-left. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make text inside the title tag animate using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731357/how-do-i-make-text-inside-the-title-tag-animate-using-javascript)

Comment: You don't have the concept of `px` in webpage titles. They're just plain strings

Comment: By the way I really don't like the linked question. Your logic is correct and I'd keep your code, just add trailing spaces to move the title

Comment: I need a date (hh:mm:ss) that changes every second and moves, not just text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first space chraracters can't be used in a html title element.
you may use a `_` instead.

```js
let tittlemov = 0;
setInterval(()=>
  { 
  document.title = '_'.repeat(tittlemov++) 
                 + new Date().toLocaleString() 
                 + '_'.repeat(10 - tittlemov);
  tittlemov %= 10;
  }, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space at each iteration:

```js
let i = 0;
function updateDateTime() {
  const datetime = new Date();
  const datetimeString = datetime.toLocaleString();
  const trailingSpaces = Array(i).fill().map(_=>' ').join('');
  document.title = trailingSpaces + datetimeString;
  i = (i + 1) % 10;
}
setInterval(updateDateTime, 100);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Date&Time marquee</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="marquee">
    <span id="datetime"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but my line doesn't run. Only time changes.